# Field Extension of degree $2$ is Normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to prove that if a field extension $E$ over $F$ is such that $$ \left[ E : F \right] = 2, $$ then $ E $ is a normal extension over $F$.

My approach to solve this is take an element $ a \in E-F, $ and find its minimal polynomial $ f(t) $.

My problem arises here. I am unsure of how to prove that $ f(t) $ is of degree $2$ and, moreover, that $E$ is the splitting field for that polynomial.

From this, it would follow that $ E $ must be normal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the degree of an extension is usually the degree of it's minimal polynomial, and it's clear that the degree of an elt is less than the degree of the minimum polynomial, so you can just jump right to $\deg(f(t))=2$ without much hassle.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I had forgotten about that. So, would the problem be  reduced to proving that the other root is in $ E $?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: It appears that I haven't grasped these concepts completely yet. It seems intuitive that $ f(t) $ has degree 2. I just can't seem to figure out why $ f(t) $ is of degree 2.

Comment: Do you know why every element of an extension has degree less than or equal to that of the extension itself?

Comment: I've never used the term degree when talking about an element, but I believe I have an idea.
If it's about the number of elements from the basis of the extension whose coefficients are non-zero, then we would have at most $ n $ of them (where $ n $ is the degree of the extension).

Comment: Yup. The degree of $t$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial generating $a$. We know $1\leq\deg(a)\leq 2$, but in fact $\deg(a)=2$ since $\deg(a)=1\Rightarrow t\in F$. Since $\deg(a)=2$ it's min poly has degree 2, so the field generated by $\{1,a\}$ is in fact $E$.